# Translate animation fallback to position

Tags: css, css-transitions

Currently i'm using elements with `position: absolute` for transitions but i should use `translate` instead. How to achive a fallback when `translate` is not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, what i was doing is that i checked if CSS3 features are supported with JS. If not, i've attached a `.fallback` class to the body so i can make separate rules as a fallback.i've added like the following:

```
#animdiv{
    transform: translate(0,100px);
}
.fallback #animdiv{
    top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having any additional information, I'm assuming you'd like to use `translate` when it is available, and `position: absolute` when it is not. I found an excellent article that lists the pros and cons, and may solve some of your woes.

http://paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Moving forward, you may want to look into the modernizr library, as it provides awesome tools for making your cutting-edge features work well on older browsers. I've posted a link to the CSS docs below.

http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css